# There is a measure $\mu^{(2)}(A_1\times A_2)=\mu(A_1\cap A_2)$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F, \mu)$ be a finite measure space, and $\mathcal E_1,\mathcal E_2$ be sub-$\sigma$-Algebras of $\mathcal F$, show that, there is a unique measure $\mu^{(2)}$ on $(\Omega\times\Omega,\mathcal E_1\otimes\mathcal E_2)$ with $\mu^{(2)}(A_1\times A_2)=\mu(A_1\cap A_2)$

If I define $f:\Omega\to\Omega\times\Omega $ with $x\mapsto(x,x)$, is then $\mu f^{-1}(A_1\times A_2)=\mu(A_1\cap A_2)$

Answer (score 2):

As for $x \in \Omega$, we have
\begin{align*}
  x \in f^{-1}(A_1 \times A_2) &\iff f(x) \in A_1 \times A_2\\
   &\iff (x,x) \in A_1 \times A_2\\
   &\iff x \in A_1 \land x \in A_2\\
   &\iff x \in A_1 \cap A_2
\end{align*}
we have $A_1 \cap A_2 = f^{-1}(A_1 \times A_2)$, as you write.